# Default proxy setting for create-react-app doesn't handle file downloads

Tags: reactjs, webpack, proxy, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I am developing a web app using `create-react-app`. I have a back-end server setup, and connect to it by setting the `proxy: ${my api host}` in `package.json`. 
I have some api calls that are supposed to return .xls file downloads. 
But can't seem to be get it through this default setup.

I changed the proxy setup with [Configuring the Proxy Manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)
 doc described in Create-React-App docs.

Now the file downloads work as expected.

I am curious why the defaults package.json proxy setting did not handle my file downloads. Somehow I had a hunch that the default proxy setting was the problem, and solved the issue, but I can't get a grip on why that was the issue.

Can anybody tell me what the underlying problem was?

Comment: This is indeed perplexing. I can see that the sec-fetch headers are different between a video tag and an anchor with download. But only after I intercept the request from the proxy middleware. Since chrome won't show anything in devtools with the default react proxy config. But I didn't modify anything except to add the middleware on that route and *poof* it works! Hate it when the solution doesn't reveal its intention. I even tried ```res.download and Content-Disposition: attachment;``` with the default proxy. For some reason ```res.download``` broke the proxy pipe. Dunno why.